# How can I directly upload image from Android to SQL Server directly without any server-side code?

Tags: android, sql-server

Actually I would like to make an application using Android and SQL server. I do not like to use ASP.Net/PHP. I want to upload images to SQL Server from Android directly.

I have sent other text-information (name, father's name, etc) but cannot upload any image directly to SQL Server from Android.

Comment: What is the reason that you can't?

Comment: Prob 1: When I try to send image to db with handset, I get message like: "Unfortunately <application_name> has stopped.
Prob 2: When I try to send image to db with emulator, it crashes

link of the full code: https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/batch---13---mobile-app-developmentandroid-seip-project/9Jiytw5N-WI/fXljgIHrEQAJ

Comment: So you do hot know what to post here if your app crashes. Sad. Read some stackoverflow pages and you know.